# Add a number to a textView using button onClick()

Tags: android

So this seems pretty simple and it probably is.

I have a textView and a Button

Every time I click the button i want to add, lets say, the number 10

Like so:

(TextView) = 0

(User clicks button)

(TextView) = 10

(User clicks button)

(TextView) = 20

and so on...

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private int i = 0;// Declare i as private
```

.....

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv01);
Btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            i = i+10;
            tv.setText( String.valueOf(i)); 
        }
    });
```